# When does React re-render child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that React performs re-render when state or props change(or when we force component to re-render). I also know that React re-renders component's children when it gets re-rendered.

I've noticed that React re-renders child component even if its props(the child props) didn't change, so when the parent component passes the same props as previously.

Why is that? And does React re-render child component which is completely stateless and propless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want child components not to re-render, you should use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent), or the [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle hook.

Each of these three options tell React that if the inputs to your component (props) don't change, then there's no point in re-rendering the component as the component won't change.

PureComponent or shouldComponentUpdate should be your go-to options if you are working with class components. Essentially, PureComponent just implements shouldComponentUpdate for you.

React.memo should be your go-to when using function components. And React.memo has a second argument for a function to determine equality, which acts similarly to shouldComponentUpdate.

You should **definitely** use one of these three options over reselect when working with react components. [Reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) is meant for memoizing selectors in redux (or just general function calls). It is not meant for memoizing react components.

I generally use reselect to make the props to the components stable (when working with connect) and prevent recomputing complex data on every render.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes sense now.

Comment: Hi, I have another question, it's not really related to the current question. So when React first calls constructor in each component and then it mounts it, when we for example change page(using react-router) or just click sth to make our component not visible and not being on the screen. And come back and see our component again, we mount this component again, but is a constructor called once again?

Comment: Yes, any time the component is removed from the page, the component has to be remounted when added back into the page. Whenever a component mounts, the whole lifecycle starts over again including the constructor and componentDidMount.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's really helpful.

Comment: From the React documentation: "This [React.memo ]method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.". Based on this I'm not sure you should use React.memo, Or am I missing something?

Comment: You should absolutely use it to improve performance of your application in critical components. However you can't rely on the component never re-rendering. Generally if you make your components pure, then you don't really need to worry about them re-rendering. In this case, an example of what not to do is put a side effect API call directly in the render function (outside of useEffect) because you expect that to only be called once due to React.Memo. That's not the point of it. React.Memo signals to react that your component doesn't *need* to re-render, not that it can't re-render.

Answer (score 1):

Why React does that by default is because it does not know to not re-render when the state is the same, unless you employ memoization on those components with a package like reselect.

What reselect helps you do is to only re-render componets when the state being passed is different from the current.

Comment: Is using PureComponent or React.Memo also an option here? Can it be used instead of reselect package?

Comment: I don't know about the other packages because I have only used Reselect. But as long as they all offer memoization it should work. Just read there documentation to know what they offer and how to integrate it.

Comment: PureComponent and React.Memo are built-in React's component's/method's.