# How does React's functional setState determine which fields have been updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

From my experimentation, if you have an object as react state (`let [state, setState] = useState({})`), and you do something like

```
setState(s => {
    s.a = 42;
    return s;
})
```

It will not re-render components that depend on `s.a`.
If on the other hand you do

```
setState(s => {...s, a: 42});
```

It will re-render all components that depend on any field of s.
So it seems to me like it really only looks at whether the returned object reference of the closure is the same as the state it already has or not and makes a binary choice whether to re-render everything or nothing.

Is that correct?

Is there any way to update state in a way that makes it only re-render things that depend on e.g. `s.a`?

CONTEXT, if it helps: I need this for my application because performance is becoming impractical. My application retrieves JSON information from and API endpoint, which contains a list of 'fields' that describe input fields that the user can use to input data. When the user is done, the application submits this data in a single json. So all input components are controlled, through a single functional state that holds one property per field (I need to be able to programmatically update some fields sometimes). Performance is prohibitive because all fields (quite many now) are updated/re-rendered every time the user types a character in one of them. I sadly cannot create a new state for each field because the amount of fields is not known in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a note before I begin, this is not okay, and does not work in general. Treat all React state/props as immutable, otherwise you'll have issues.

```
setState(s => {
    s.a = 42;
    return s;
})
```

There is no way to selectively re-render your component, the reason why that mutation on setState doesn't re-render children that depend on s.a is because your component doesn't re-render at all when you update like this because the reference of s doesn't change, so react doesn't see that there's a change.

The only way to make children not re-render when parents re-render is to use React.memo, PureComponent, or shouldComponentUpdate. And those have to be applied to the children rather than the parent.

[When does React re-render child component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61523675/when-does-react-re-render-child-component/61524390#61524390)