# Why does React re-render child components even when passing props memoized with useMemo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I came across this answer, which appears to address this: [When does React re-render child component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61523675/when-does-react-re-render-child-component)

But I'm asking a little more nuanced question here. Why does React re-render child components (generally) when using the `useMemo` hook?

In the below example, I'd expect both `Child` and `Mchild` components not re-render on an input onChange event, but only `Mchild` doesn't re-render. `Child` renders on every keypress.

Could anyone shed some light on why React does this? I suppose what I'm asking is, I don't understand why React doesn't do this by default. What would be the disadvantage of using a child component pattern that always uses `React.memo`?

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";

const Child = ({ person, which }: any) => {
  console.log(`${which} render`);

  return <div>{`From child component: ${person.first}`}</div>;
};

const Mchild = React.memo(Child);

function Parent() {
  console.log("Parent render");

  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>("");

  const person = { first: "gary", last: "johnson" };
  const mPerson = useMemo(() => person, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        MESSAGE:{" "}
        <input value={message} onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)} />
      </div>

      <div>Parent</div>

      <Child person={mPerson} which="Child" />
      <Mchild person={mPerson} which="Mchild" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Parent;
```

Comment: I posted an answer to explain things from the ground up. Please check my latest edit and let me know :)

Comment: Thank you Yousoumar. So to summarize your answer -- React doesn't use React.memo by default b/c it's more expensive than just allowing the child components to re-render, unless of course it isn't, at which point you'd use React.memo explicitly?

Comment: My pleasure @Gary :) I have added one last case that I did not mention before when your memorized component wraps another component. Check it and let me know!

Comment: How do you measure how expensive a re-render is vs. a React.memo invocation?

Comment: There is no known method for that, as far as I know. You could use React Devtools extension. But don't worry too much about memoization, do it only when you realize a slowness while using your app.

Comment: I still don’t know why react doesn’t do this by default — use react.memo. You said bc it’s expensive. How so? Based on what metrics? How do you know?

Comment: I have just added below a quote about why I say it’s expensive to compare. You can check it.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated Yousoumar.

Comment: It's my pleasure to share. Have a good one :)

Comment: I gave more thought to this and here's my conclusion -- we're evaluating O(number of shallow comparisons [one per prop]) vs. a re-render of the child component; I'm fairly confident that a re-render of the child component is more compute intensive than a few shallow comparisons so I'm still not sure why React.memo isn't the default. Maybe it's an issue of practicality -- that most apps wouldn't use the useMemo hook for props so they opted for full child re-renders every time.

Answer (score 8):

A component re-renders when its internal state changes or its parent re-render. React doesn't memoize everything by default because, first, most re-renders are not expansive, and second, to be able to memoize, you need a comparison algorithm, which is not free, as [Dan Abramov](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov), one of the maintainers [says](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1095661142477811717):

> Shallow comparisons aren’t free. They’re O(prop count). And they only buy something if it bails out. All comparisons where we end up re-rendering are wasted.
>
> Why would you expect always comparing to be faster? Considering many components always get different props.

```js
// Default rendering behavior overview 

const SimpleChild = () => {
  console.log("SimpleChild render");
  return <div></div>;
};

function Parent() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(true);
  console.clear();
  console.log("Parent render");
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Default rendering behavior overview </p>
      <SimpleChild  />
      <button onClick={() => setState((prev) => !prev)}>Render Parent</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

A component re-rendering because of its parent re-rendering may be problematic, if this child does expansive computing tasks, without being affected by the parent re-render. In this case, you can tell React not to re-render this child when the parent re-renders, with [`memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo):

```js
// Memoizing with memo

const HeavyChild = React.memo(() => {
  console.log("HeavyChild render");
  return <div></div>;
});

function Parent() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(true);
  console.clear();
  console.log("Parent render");
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Memoizing with memo</p>
      <HeavyChild  />
      <button onClick={() => setState((prev) => !prev)}>Render Parent</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Now, what happens if we pass an object to the above memoized `HeavyChild`? Well, our [`memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) won't do what we want anymore. This is because [`memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) does "something like":

```js
if (prevPropsValue === currentPropsValue) { 
    // Don not re-render
}
```

But an object defined in the parent gets re-created on a new reference on each re-render, so it's a new value.

```js
// Memoizing with memo when an object is passed as props

const HeavyChild = React.memo(() => {
  console.log("HeavyChild render");
  return <div></div>;
});

function Parent() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(true);
  const someObject = {}
  console.clear();
  console.log("Parent render");
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Memoizing with memo when an object is passed as props</p>
      <HeavyChild someObject={someObject}  />
      <button onClick={() => setState((prev) => !prev)}>Render Parent</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

If you wanna avoid the above behavior when it comes to objects being passed as props, you can use [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), to memoize the object:

> We have the same behavior as objects when it comes to functions being passed as props, in which case we use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to memoize them.

```js
// Memoizing with memo when a memoized object is passed as props

const HeavyChild = React.memo(() => {
  console.log("HeavyChild render");
  return <div></div>;
});

function Parent() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(true);
  const someMemoizedObject = React.useMemo(()=>{}, [])
  console.clear();
  console.log("Parent render");
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Memoizing with memo when a memoized object is passed as props</p>
      <HeavyChild someMemoizedObject={someMemoizedObject}  />
      <button onClick={() => setState((prev) => !prev)}>Render Parent</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

And the last thing to know is that [`memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) won't work as expected if `HeavyChild` wrap a child component that can be consumed with `children`, as in this case, `children` is, as of now, always a new reference.

```js
// Memoizing with memo when a component is passed as children

const SomeNestedChild = () => {
  return <div></div>;
};

const HeavyChild = React.memo(({children}) => {
  console.log("HeavyChild render");
  return <div></div>;
});

function Parent() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(true);
  
  console.clear();
  console.log("Parent render");
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Memoizing with memo when a component is passed as children</p>
      <HeavyChild><SomeNestedChild/></HeavyChild>
      <button onClick={() => setState((prev) => !prev)}>Render Parent</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see first when React components re-render. React children will re-render when either their props/state change or their parent component re-renders.

In your case, the Child will re-render since there is a state change in the parent component. Whenever you type in the input field, the state message changes, causing the parent component to re-render, hence the Child component will re-render.

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>("");
```

In order to make your Child component only re-render when its prop changes, you need to memoize it, like you have done with `MChild`. Now `MChild` will only re-render when its prop changes, which is exactly the case of yours.